# flex sdk version problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

Well  i am using following tools
flex builder 3.2
sdk 4.1 
Flash Player 10

and i get this error.
Verify Error: Error #1053: Illegal override of isRelatedObjectInaccessible in RemappedMouseEvent.

when I clean the project and run it and get the same error.. i tried all the things expect updating the Flex builder plugin as it was mentioned as solution at this link.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2942084#671952

i don't find any link that can update flex-builder 3.2 and i am using updated sdk still i need updated plugin for Flex builder 3.2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like this are commonly caused by a version mismatch.  Are you using a components in external SWCs or other projects?  Make sure that those SWCs/proejcts are compiled against the same SDK version as your main project.

I do not believe that the Flex Builder Plugin was updated for every update to the Flex SDK.  But, Flex Builder should work with any version of the Flex SDK.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that changing your IDE would address a compile time or runtime errors.  There must have been a change in SDK versioning that also happened when you changed IDE, right?